# Keep the time format in an Excel column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

I've been attempting to resolve a seemingly simple issue that, despite consulting Stack Overflow, has proven elusive.

I have an Excel sheet with a column labeled 'Franquia,' and its entries are formatted as follows:

Franquia

08:00:00

15:00:00.

24:00:00

30:00:00

06:00:00

and so forth.

Upon importing it as a DataFrame using:

`df = pd.read_excel('~/Desktop/controle_de_horas_2023.xlsx')`

The 'Franquia' column is of type datetime.time, and its format becomes incorrect when the time exceeds 23:59:00.

For instance:

24:00:00 transforms into 1900-01-01 00:00:00

30:00:00 transforms into 1900-01-01 06:00:00

I need the hours to retain the original format from the Excel sheet. How can I achieve this?

I tried some parameters when importing:

`converters={'Franquia': str} dtype={'Franquia': str}`

converting to_timedelta witch gave an error...

I need it in some shape like 30:00:00